# Joining two table using nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have two tables:

```
Product(ProductID, Detail, ProductTypeID)
```

and

```
ProductType(ProductTypeID, Detail).
```

I want to get a list of `ProductType` which `ProductTypeID` is Product table using `nhibernate`. There are a huge amount of product type.

Comment: ORMs are used so you don't have to make joins to retrieve related objects. Specify your relations in your nhibernate.cfg and the related objects will be loaded automatically when you ask for their parents

Answer (score -1):

In NHibernate we write queries against the object model, not the tables. Since you don't describe your object model, I have made a straigthforward assumption based on how your tables look.

One possible query, using NHibernate Linq would then be like this:

```
// Notice no ToList(), since we want it as a subquery.
var usedProductTypesIdSubquery =
    session.Query<Product>
           .Select(product => product.ProductType.Id);

var usedProductTypes = 
    session.Query<ProductType>
           .Where(productType => usedProductTypesIdSubquery.Contains(productType.Id)
           .ToList();

// Because we are using a subquery, and contains (the 'IN' clause in SQL), the
// resulting list usedProductTypes will not contain duplicates.
```